# What is an efficient alternative for an extremely large HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to break a symmetric encryption using a 'meet-in-the-middle' attack. For this I need to store 2**32 integer-integer pairs. I'm storing the mapping from a 4-byte cyphertext to a 4-byte key.

At first I tried using an array, but then I realized that you cannot have such a big array in java (the max size is bound by `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

Now I'm using a HashMap, but this gets way too slow when the map gets large, even when increasing the max memory to 8GB with `-Xmx8192M`.

***What is an efficient alternative for an extremely large HashMap?***

This is the code I'm currently using to populate my hashmap:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
// Loop until integer overflow
for (int k = 1; k != 0; k++)
    map.put(encrypt_left(c, k), k);
```

I haven't seen this code finish, even after letting it run for hours. Progress logging shows that the first 2**24 values are created in 22s, but then the performance quickly decreases.

Comment: Array could work as you have integer keys.

Comment: @Bubletan No, it wouldn't, because it only allows positive indexes.

Comment: Use *two* arrays? Why give up just one step before success?

Comment: You can use a custom hashing where the hashcode leads to an offset in multiple arrays. Or if binary search lookups are fast enough, then use sorted entries in multiple arrays (pivot at 1/16-tile). But I am quite sure that there are more fance methods for such attacks. (and of course you can keep key and value in seperate arrays).

Comment: A hashmap with buckets (or worse trees) will need at least 40bytes/entry. So you need 80-160GB for such a structure. When you can reduce this to simple arrays you might get it down to 32GB. No idea how you would fit that into 8GB without a probabilistic approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm storing the mapping from a 4-byte cyphertext to a 4-byte key.

Conveniently, 4 bytes is an `int`. As you observed, array sizes are limited by `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. That suggests you *can* use an array – but there's a minor hangup. Integers are signed, but arrays only permit values >=0.

So you create *two* arrays: one for the positive cyphertexts, and one for the negative cyphertexts. Then you just need to make sure that you've given the JVM enough heap.

How much heap is that?

4 bytes * `Integer.MAX_VALUE` * 2 arrays
= 17179869176 bytes
= ~16.0 gigabytes.

Comment: Unfortunately, my machine only has 8GB RAM. Does this mean I cannot do it on this pc?

Comment: It means your computer does not physically have enough RAM to hold all that data in memory at once. You may need to use a different algorithm – one that does not require holding everything in memory. You could give the JVM more heap space than you have physical RAM but swapping will _wreck_ your program's performance.

Comment: No, but it means you're going to be thrashing your hard drive.  Hope it's a solid state.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Hmm ok let's not do that :p

Comment: Don't forget you also need room in your ram for other things, like your operating system.

Comment: I opted for the simple solution and bought some more memory :p I managed to break it in 10 minutes using 4 lookup arrays.

Comment: @popovitsj nice. Why 4 arrays and not 2?

Comment: Because as it turns out, if I create an array as `new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE]`, it gives an OutOfMemoryError with the message Requested array size exceeds VM limit. It seems the largest I can create is `new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1]`. But actually, even `Integer.MAX_VALUE` would be too small, because it's 2**31 - 1.

Answer (score 2):

When building a rainbow table, consider the size of data, you are going to produce. Consider also the fact, that this problem can be solved without vast amounts of RAM. This is done by using files instead of putting all in memory. Typically you build files of the size that fits in your file buffer. For example 4096 bytes or 8192 bytes. If you get a key, you just divide it by the file buffer's size, load the file and look at mod x position.
The tricky part is that you need the encrypted data to be layed out, and not the key. So you start with dummy files and write the key data at the position of the encrypted data.

So let's say, your key is 1026 and the encrypted data is 126. The flke to write 1026 to is 0.rbt because 126*4 byte / 4096 = 0. The position is 126*4 byte.
And of course you need the nio classes for that.

Answer (score 2):

Following the advice of @MattBall, I implemented my own `BigArray`, which composes a 32-bit length array from 4 separate arrays.

Running this without the suggested JVM arguments will cause an OutOfMemoryError. Using this with the suggested JVM arguments but with too little RAM will probably cause your machine to crash.

```
/**
 * Array that holds 2**32 integers, Implemented as four 30-bit arrays.
 * <p>
 * Requires 16 GB RAM solely for the array allocation. 
 * <p>
 * Example JVM Arguments: <code>-Xmx22000M -Xms17000M</code>
 * <p>
 * This sets the max memory to 22,000 MB and the initial memory to 17,000 MB
 * <p>
 * WARNING: don't use these settings if your machine does not have this much RAM.
 * 
 * @author popovitsj
 */
public class BigArray
{

    private int[] a_00= new int[1 << 30];
    private int[] a_01 = new int[1 << 30];
    private int[] a_10 = new int[1 << 30];
    private int[] a_11 = new int[1 << 30];

    private static final int A_00 = 0;
    private static final int A_01 = 1 << 30;
    private static final int A_10 = 1 << 31;
    private static final int A_11 = 3 << 30;
    private static final int A_30 = A_01 - 1;

    public void set(int index, int value)
    {
        getArray(index)[index & A_30] = value;
    }

    public int get(int index)
    {
        return getArray(index)[index & A_30];
    }

    private int[] getArray(int index)
    {
        switch (index & A_11)
        {
        case (A_00):
            return a_00;
        case (A_01):
            return a_01;
        case (A_10):
            return a_10;
        default:
            return a_11;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat. Thanks for sharing your own solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is big data problem, in this case it is more of a big memory problem. The computation should be done in memory for performance. Use Hazelcast distributed  `HashMap`. It is very easy to use and very performant.
You can use more than 2 or more machines for your problem.

Sample usage :

```
HazelcastInstance hzInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
Map<Integer, Integer> map = hzInstance.getMap("map1");
map.put(x,y);
..
```